# Determine the classes referenced in a .class file

Tags: java

What's the best way to (programmatically) parse a compiled Java (.class) file and generate a list of any and all other Java classes it references?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy do it by yourself if you know [the spec](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=202).

Heres a quick and dirty demo program how to do it:

```
package test;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    private static Map<Integer, String> strings = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private static Set<Integer> classes = new HashSet<Integer>();
    private static int indexCorrection = 0; // for correcting indexes to constant pools with long and double entries

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        printReferencedClassesFromClass(String.class);
    }

    private static void printReferencedClassesFromClass(Class<?> c) throws IOException {
        saveReferencedClassesFromStream(c.getResourceAsStream(c.getSimpleName() + ".class"));
        printReferencedClasses();
    }

    private static void printReferencedClasses() {
        for (Integer index : classes)
            System.out.println(strings.get(index));
    }

    private static void saveReferencedClassesFromStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream dataStream = new DataInputStream(stream);
        skipHeader(dataStream);
        saveReferencedClassesFromConstantPool(dataStream);
    }

    private static void skipHeader(DataInputStream dataInputStream) throws IOException {
        readU4(dataInputStream); // magic byte
        readU2(dataInputStream); // minor version
        readU2(dataInputStream); // major version
    }

    private static void saveReferencedClassesFromConstantPool(DataInputStream stream) throws IOException {
        int poolSize = readU2(stream);
        for (int n = 1; n < poolSize - indexCorrection; n++)
            savePoolEntryIfIsClassReference(n, stream);
    }

    private static void savePoolEntryIfIsClassReference(int index, DataInputStream stream) throws IOException {
        int tag = readU1(stream);
        switch (tag) {
        case 1: // Utf8
            saveStringFromUtf8Entry(index, stream);
            break;
        case 7: // Class
            saveClassEntry(stream);
            break;
        case 8: // String
        case 16: // MethodType
            readU2(stream);
            break;
        case 3: // Integer
        case 4: // Float
            readU4(stream);
            break;
        case 5: // Long
        case 6: // Double
            readU4(stream);
            readU4(stream);
            indexCorrection++;
            break;
        case 9: // Fieldref
        case 10: // Methodref
        case 11: // InterfaceMethodref
        case 12: // NameAndType
        case 18: // InvokeDynmaic
            readU2(stream);
            readU2(stream);
            break;
        case 15: // MethodHandle
            readU1(stream);
            readU2(stream);
            break;
        }
    }

    private static void saveClassEntry(DataInputStream stream) throws IOException {
        classes.add(readU2(stream));
    }

    private static void saveStringFromUtf8Entry(int index, DataInputStream stream) throws IOException {
        strings.put(index + indexCorrection, readString(stream));
    }

    private static String readString(DataInputStream stream) throws IOException {
        return stream.readUTF();
    }

    private static int readU1(DataInputStream stream) throws IOException {
        return stream.readUnsignedByte();
    }

    private static int readU2(DataInputStream stream) throws IOException {
        return stream.readUnsignedShort();
    }

    private static int readU4(DataInputStream stream) throws IOException {
        return stream.readInt();
    }

}
```

Output is:

```
test/Main
java/lang/Object
java/io/BufferedInputStream
java/util/Iterator
java/io/FileInputStream
java/lang/System
java/lang/Integer
java/lang/Exception
java/lang/String
java/io/File
java/util/Map
java/util/HashMap
java/io/IOException
java/util/Set
java/io/DataInputStream
java/io/PrintStream
java/util/HashSet
java/lang/Throwable
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work every time, must be a bug somewhere. Try it on `ImmutableSetMultimap.class` from guava-17. It will treat "Invalid key count " string as a class name. In addition, try adding `default` section to `switch(tag)`: it will get triggered at the very end of constant pool with `tag==0`

Comment: I fixed the bug and adapted the code to work with java 8. It is expectable to break again with newer class file formats if these add additional tag types to the constant pool.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried JDepend? It analyzes class files to determine references.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do with Apache's [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the best way is. I do know there are 2 APIs that might help.

You can try jclasslib, for inspecting .class files
http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jclasslib/resources.html
or BCEL (byte code engineering library) for analyzing and manipulating .class files.
http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/

My understanding is that any class to be used within a .class (as far as a field, parameter, return type, etc) is defined in the constant_pool. So you may want to read up on that.
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use my [Java Dependency Resolver project](http://code.google.com/p/java-dependency-resolver/) Which will find the not only the referenced java files but also the jars for a particular class in a Project