# How to find all referenced classes from a .class file?

Tags: java, class, dependencies

Find class dependency is a common issue, but maybe it is not a trivial work to find all referenced classes from a .class file.

I have seen [the solution provided by Arne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753337/determine-the-classes-referenced-in-a-class-file/21089532#21089532).  But this solution does not work for the following situation:

```
 public class ClassA {
     private B b ;
     class B {
        ClassC c;
     } 
 }
```

since I cannot get the info for ClassC from neither ClassA.class nor ClassA$B.class.

Who knows how to handle such a situation?

Thanks.

Robin

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question you're asking. Are you trying to: (a) build a list of all classes a given class references; (b) physically locate a list of classes, which you happened have generated by analyzing class dependencies; or (c) none of the above?

Comment: I want to analyse class dependencies, so I have to get all referenced class information from a .class file.