# Get ByteCode (dependency) information from .class files through Java

Tags: java, java-8, bytecode, jdeps

I would like to analyse `.class` files and get information about which class uses which other class.

`jdeps` is a command line tool which allows you to display some information in the console, but I would like to avoid calling an external tool and scraping the command line output.

Comment: and you can't do that from an IDE? Just wondering... also seems like http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/ could do that, but I have not tried

Comment: Thank you for the hint. This is about analysing 50000 Java artifacts programmatically.

Comment: AFAIK `javap` has not programatic access, but of course you could use a process for that and invoke it and then parse output; it seems that simply a `grep` would be enough in your case to simply search for that class. I just wonder if there would be any issues with inheritance though... I like the question

Comment: Take a look into [asm](http://download.forge.ow2.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753337/determine-the-classes-referenced-in-a-class-file

Answer (score 6):

All dependencies are recorded at a central place of a class file, the constant pool. So to efficiently process all dependencies, you need a library allowing to process the constant pool without looking at the rest of the class file (which rules out ASM, which is otherwise a very good bytecode processing library).

So using, e.g. [Javassist](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/), you can do the job as

```
private static Set<String> getDependencies(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ClassFile cf = new ClassFile(new DataInputStream(is));
    ConstPool constPool = cf.getConstPool();
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(int ix = 1, size = constPool.getSize(); ix < size; ix++) {
        int descriptorIndex;
        switch (constPool.getTag(ix)) {
            case ConstPool.CONST_Class: set.add(constPool.getClassInfo(ix));
            default: continue;
            case ConstPool.CONST_NameAndType:
                descriptorIndex = constPool.getNameAndTypeDescriptor(ix);
                break;
            case ConstPool.CONST_MethodType:
                descriptorIndex = constPool.getMethodTypeInfo(ix);
        }
        String desc = constPool.getUtf8Info(descriptorIndex);
        for(int p = 0; p<desc.length(); p++)
            if(desc.charAt(p)=='L')
                set.add(desc.substring(++p, p = desc.indexOf(';', p)).replace('/', '.'));
    }
    return set;
}
```

Testing it with

```
try(InputStream is = String.class.getResourceAsStream("String.class")) {
    set = getDependencies(is);
}
set.stream().sorted().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

shows

```
[B
[C
[I
[Ljava.lang.CharSequence;
[Ljava.lang.String;
java.io.ObjectStreamField
java.io.Serializable
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder
java.lang.CharSequence
java.lang.Character
java.lang.Comparable
java.lang.Double
java.lang.Float
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
java.lang.Integer
java.lang.Iterable
java.lang.Long
java.lang.Math
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.Object
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
java.lang.String
java.lang.String$1
java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator
java.lang.StringBuffer
java.lang.StringBuilder
java.lang.StringCoding
java.lang.StringCoding$Result
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
java.lang.StringLatin1
java.lang.StringLatin1$CharsSpliterator
java.lang.StringUTF16
java.lang.StringUTF16$CharsSpliterator
java.lang.StringUTF16$CodePointsSpliterator
java.lang.System
java.lang.Throwable
java.lang.Void
java.nio.charset.Charset
java.util.ArrayList
java.util.Arrays
java.util.Comparator
java.util.Formatter
java.util.Iterator
java.util.List
java.util.Locale
java.util.Objects
java.util.Spliterator
java.util.Spliterator$OfInt
java.util.StringJoiner
java.util.regex.Matcher
java.util.regex.Pattern
java.util.stream.IntStream
java.util.stream.StreamSupport
```

<sup>(on Java 9)</sup>

---

You can get to the same result using [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/):

```
private static Set<String> getDependencies(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    JavaClass cf = new ClassParser(is, "").parse();
    ConstantPool constPool = cf.getConstantPool();
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    constPool.accept(new DescendingVisitor(cf, new EmptyVisitor() {
        @Override public void visitConstantClass(ConstantClass cC) {
            set.add(((String)cC.getConstantValue(constPool)).replace('/', '.'));
        }
        @Override public void visitConstantNameAndType(ConstantNameAndType cNaT) {
            processSignature(cNaT.getSignature(constPool));
        }
        @Override public void visitConstantMethodType(ConstantMethodType cMt) {
            processSignature(
                constPool.constantToString(cMt.getDescriptorIndex(),
                (byte)ConstPool.CONST_Utf8));
        }
        private void processSignature(String desc) {
            for(int p = 0; p<desc.length(); p++)
                if(desc.charAt(p)=='L')
                    set.add(desc.substring(++p, p=desc.indexOf(';', p)).replace('/', '.'));
        }
    }));
    return set;
}
```

Comment: I was really really hoping you would answer this one!

Comment: Thank you. What do the first five entries (with the [ at the beginning) mean?

Comment: @JFMeier these names are in the [“Binary names”](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#name) format, whereas `[B`, `[C`, `[I` denote `byte[]`, `char[]`, and `int[]`. `[Ljava.lang.CharSequence;` and `[Ljava.lang.String;` refer to `CharSequence[]` and `String[]`. Basically, it’s the JVM internal name, but `/` replaced with `.`.

Comment: I can't get either of these to work. The current versions of those libraries have changed too much for me to adapt this code in the 40 minutes I've spent at it.

Comment: @JosephJaquinta you can use the solution of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19928470/2711488) which doesn’t depend on other libraries, hence, can’t become obsoleted by library changes.