# How can I identify classes which will be used in java class file

Tags: java, bytecode, classloading

How can I identify java classes which will be used in a java `*.class` file by parsing the compiled `*.class` file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you going to use any class-parsing library in your runtime or using `javap foo/Bar.class | grep -P '#\d+ = Class'` would be enough?

Comment: Too little information about your requirements. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50040336/2711488) does it using open source libraries whereas [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19928470/2711488) does without additional libraries.